# Why does "increment" not set an identity seed in SQL Server 2008

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008

I am trying to learn nhibernate 3.0 and I tried to put this in my mapping

```
<id name="MovieId">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
```

However when I generate my database it makes MovieId as a int(what I want) but it does not put identity seed on.

When I use

```
   <id name="MovieId">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
```

it works. I am not sure what native really is and why it works. I though increment does ints.

Comment: I heard that the mapping files in nHibernate are no longer popular, I didn't know people still preferred them...(just a thought)

Comment: ya it seems most ppl recommend fluent but a project I am going to be working on uses mapping so I need to know the basics before I try to do fluent mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generator should be "identity" or "native" instead of the "increment". "Native" uses "sequence" for databases like "PostGres" or "Oracle" and "identity" for MSSQL. It allows the same app to run on different databases without changing mappings.

"Increment" increments IDs in memory (instead of the DB) which creates several flaws like an inability to scale the application across multiple servers or use the same DB by multiple applications.